# Genitive: declining noun + adjective pairs with numbers

Tags: числительные, множественное-число, родительный-падеж

I am an intermediate student of Russian, and in one of my courses I came across the following example:

> Тут два белых стула. — Two white chairs are here.

My understanding is that the genitive is generally used with numbers, and here the adjective `белый` is declined to the genitive plural `белых`, so I would expect the noun to also be declined to the genitive plural `стульев`. **However, the example uses the genitive singular `стула` for "chairs".**

Why is this the case, and is there a "rule" that addresses this type of sentence?

For clarity and contrast, here is another example in the genitive that declines the way I was expecting:

> У меня нет двух белых стульев. — I do not have two white chairs.

Comment: This point's been widely discussed: [Does the Russian numeral rule for the adjective that comes between the number and the noun (see below) apply to animate nouns in actual usage?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/14917/does-the-russian-numeral-rule-for-the-adjective-that-comes-between-the-number-an) and
 [Can anyone clear up some discrepancies between rules for numeral+adjective+noun agreement for 2/3/4 and actual usage (as found through e-sources)?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/14915/can-anyone-clear-up-some-discrepancies-between-rules-for-numeraladjectivenoun)

Comment: And also [Я вижу + numeral + noun - governed by what case?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/13618/Я-вижу-numeral-noun-governed-by-what-case). You could have found that all yourself.

Comment: @YellowSky thank you for the links, but your comment isn't helpful. Obviously if my searches had given me the threads, I wouldn't have asked the question in the first place. I will mark it redundant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a complex area of Russian grammar. All grammar texts address this; but Derrek Offord's *"Modern Russian: An Advanced Grammar Course"* [Offord][1] addresses it better than many, at least for non-native learners. It's out of print now, but it can still be found. On page 222, here's what Offord has to say about this very topic:

> When два/две, оба/обе, полтора/полторы, три & четыре are themselves
> are used in the nominative or accusative case the noun that follows
> them is in the genitive singular case.

e.g. два стула

But why genitive plural for the adjective белых in your first example? Again, Offord p.222:

> If an adjective is used with a noun after any of these numerals then
> it will be in the genitive plural if the noun is masculine or neuter,
> and in the nominative/accusative plural (or possibly genitive plural)
> if the noun is feminine.

Therefore, Тут два белых стула, but Тут две белые книги.

The cognitive hurdle here is created by the breakage of the seemingly inviolable rule of adjective-noun agreement in case and number.

[1]: Offord, Derek. *Modern Russian: An Advanced Grammar Course.* Reprinted with corr, Bristol Classical Press, 1994.